# Symfony4: disabling services that you rarely use

Tags: performance, service, constructor, symfony4

It seems all symfony services are always *__constructed*, even if you don't use them. Is that right ?

If you have services in symfony that you rarely use, like an import service that you only use once, doesn't that impact the load on every call ? Is there a standard way of disabling them when not needed anymore ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when a service isn't used (in that it needs to be injected into a service or something) its constructor won't be called:

> When you ask for the MessageGenerator service, the container constructs a new MessageGenerator object and returns it (see sidebar below). **But if you never ask for the service, it’s never constructed**: saving memory and speed. As a bonus, the MessageGenerator service is only created once: the same instance is returned each time you ask for it.
>
> source: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container.html

You can even more lazily manage services via proxies. That's when instead of actually returning the service you return a wrapper that only calls the wrapped service's constructor if and when some method is called on it. However this requires some extra setup, see https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/lazy_services.html

So, essentially: You shouldn't need to disable services, since they're not created unless you have active code that requires it. If you have lots of *heavy* services that are used somewhere, you might want lazy-loading, if the services are injected but still not used.